# How can i make a spotify command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify, discord.py

Spotify Command

i tried a lot of things and i cant get this to work

```py
@client.command()
async def spotify(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
        embedspotify = discord.Embed(title=f"{user.name}'s Spotify", color=0x1eba10)
        embedspotify.add_field(name="Song", value=Spotify.title)
        embedspotify.add_field(name="Artist", value=Spotify.artist)
        embedspotify.add_field(name="Album", value=Spotify.album)
        embedspotify.set_thumbnail(url=Spotify.album_cover_url)
```

i am trying to get spotifytitle of the song,name of artist and name of album of the person i use command on(when they are listening to spotify)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the [`Spotify`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#spotify) instance from the list of activities the `Member` is performing:

```
@client.command()
@commands.guild_only() # We can only access activities from a guild
async def spotify(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    user = user or ctx.author  # default to the caller
    spot = next((activity for activity in user.activities if isinstance(activity, discord.Spotify)), None)
    if spot is None:
        await ctx.send(f"{user.name} is not listening to Spotify")
        return
    embedspotify = discord.Embed(title=f"{user.name}'s Spotify", color=0x1eba10)
    embedspotify.add_field(name="Song", value=spot.title)
    embedspotify.add_field(name="Artist", value=spot.artist)
    embedspotify.add_field(name="Album", value=spot.album)
    embedspotify.set_thumbnail(url=spot.album_cover_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedspotify)
```

Answer (score 0):

Command works great, i decided to add in the embed the track link via `track_id`

`[{spot.title}](https://open.spotify.com/track/{spot.track_id})`

````
async def spotify(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    user = user or ctx.author  
    spot = next((activity for activity in user.activities if isinstance(activity, discord.Spotify)), None)
    if spot is None:
        await ctx.send(f"{user.name} is not listening to Spotify")
        return
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{user.name}'s Spotify", color=spot.color)
    embed.add_field(name="Song", value=spot.title)
    embed.add_field(name="Artist", value=spot.artist)
    embed.add_field(name="Album", value=spot.album)
    embed.add_field(name="Track Link", value=f"[{spot.title}](https://open.spotify.com/track/{spot.track_id})")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=spot.album_cover_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        print(f'{user.name} in {ctx.guild} called the command !spotify')```
````